# why python AST module parse a source code to a tree of it's node don't have point of parent

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I use AST module to parse a source code, and process it for something. But, when I need back a parent node from its child node, it's didn't exist.

Comment: You might find this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8340567/270986

Comment: You're simply stating a fact, and rather vaguely I must say. What's your question?

Answer (score -1):

you can always store your parent node in a heap for later use.